# Drag and drop elements outside/inside google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api, draggable

I know its already answered here: 
[google maps drag and drop objects into google maps from outside the Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510972/google-maps-drag-and-drop-objects-into-google-maps-from-outside-the-map),
But its not exactly what i need.

I have a **"Pokemon-Shop"** website with shopping card.

[image]

When users checkout there order,
 i want to let them drag the items into google map, and then popup the drop location.

[image]

And i have another problem:

**Every drop need to saved in object with the item details and drop location, And every item on the map should be an option to return back to shopping-card.**

Is it possible?

Comment: Here I made an example of how to drag a marker from the map to the outside. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245059/is-it-possible-to-drag-google-maps-marker-and-drop-it-in-listview/32254583#32254583

Comment: Thank you! But i need to drag item into google map before i drag it outside.

Comment: Yes, you need to handle both.  Then with every drag-in and drag-out you must update the data.  I'll see if I can write a usable example

Comment: It can be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good start.
Dragging in and out of the map works pretty well.

add your API key

```
<style>
  html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
  }
  html, body, ul, li {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style: none;
  }
  #dropzone {
    width: 10%;
    height: 500px;
  }
  #map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
  }
  #dropzone li {
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
  }
  #dropzone li img {
    height: 64px;
  }
  #dropzone .message {
    color: #ff0000;
    font: +1;
  }
</style>

<div id="map" style=""></div>
<ul id="dropzone">
</ul>
<p>You can drag the icons inside the map, and you can drag the back out by dragging them to the left of the map</p>
<input id="dragged"><br>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var iconWidth = 64;
var iconHeight = 64;
var pokemonData = [
  {
    id: '001',
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    icon: 'http://www.poke-amph.com/frlg/sprites/large/002.png',
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    name: 'Ivysaur',
    icon: 'http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/b/b0/Spr_3r_002.png',
  },
  {
    id: '003',
    name: 'Pikachu',
    icon: 'http://pldh.net/media/pokemon/gen3/emerald/025.png',
  },
  {
    id: '004',
    name: 'Charmander',
    icon: 'http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/e9/Spr_3f_004.png',
  }];
var map;
var overlay; // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510972/google-maps-drag-and-drop-objects-into-google-maps-from-outside-the-map

// when the draggable image is dragged into the map.
// this is where you want to handle transaction prices ... 
function dragIn(e, icon, index) {
    var x = e.pageX - $('#map').offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY;
    if(x > 0) {
      // the image is inside the position of the map

      // skip doubles
      if(pokemonData[index].marker) {  // if you allow multiple of the same icons, remove this
        return true;
      }
      var point=new google.maps.Point(x, y);
      var position = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
      // add position to the object
      pokemonData[index].mapPosition = [position.lat(), position.lng()];
      generateMarkers([pokemonData[index]]);
      // reset icon position.  Feel free to hilight , or hide something ...
      $(icon).attr('style', 'position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;');
      $('#dropzone li').eq(index).find('.message').html('on map: ' + position.lat().toFixed(6) +','+ position.lng().toFixed(6));
      // TODO: add extra stuff here

    }
}

// when the draggable marker is dragged out of the map.
// this is where you want to handle transaction prices ... 
function dragOut(e, marker, index) {
  map.setOptions({draggable: true});
  // remove the marker from the map
  marker.setMap(null);
  pokemonData[index].marker = null;
  // extra display things
  var content = '<img src="'+ pokemonData[index].icon +'"/><br/>' + pokemonData[index].name;
  $('#dropzone li').eq(index).find('.message').html('marker taken off map');
  // TODO: add extra stuff here
}

function updateMarkerPosition(e, marker) {
  var index = pokemonData.itemIndex('marker', marker);
  var position = e.latLng;
  // update position
  $('#dropzone li').eq(index).find('.message').html('on map: ' + position.lat().toFixed(6) +','+ position.lng().toFixed(6));
}

function generatePageMarkers(data) {
  for (var i in data) {
    if(data[i].id) {
      var content = '<li><img data-id="'+ data[i].id +'" class="dragicon" src="'+ data[i].icon +'"/><br/><span class="name">' + data[i].name + '</span><div class="message"></div></li>';
      $('#dropzone').append(content);
    }
  }
  $('.dragicon').draggable({
      stop: function(e, ui) {
      var index = pokemonData.itemIndex('id', $(this).data('id'));
      dragIn(e, this, index);
    }
  });
}

function generateMarkers(data) {
    // generate the markers
    for (var i in data) {
      if(!data[i].id) {
        break;
      }
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].mapPosition[0], data[i].mapPosition[1]),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        //icon: data[i].icon,
        icon: {
          url: data[i].icon,
          size: google.maps.Size(iconWidth, iconHeight),
          target: google.maps.Point(iconWidth/2, iconHeight/2),
          origin: google.maps.Point(iconWidth/2, iconHeight/2)
        } ,
        title: data[i].name
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
        map.setOptions({draggable: true});
        updateMarkerPosition(e, this);
      })

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(e) {
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        var pixelPosition =  getPixelPosition(this);
        //var index = markers.indexOf(this);
        var index = pokemonData.itemIndex('marker', this);
        //if (pixelPosition.right <= 60) {// Get the marker out of the map
        if (pixelPosition.x <= 10) {// Get the marker out of the map
          dragOut(e, this, index);
        }
        //document.getElementById("dragged").value = 'x: ' + pixelPosition.x +' - right:'+ pixelPosition.right;
      })
      // store the variable in the array
      // markers.push(marker);
      data[i].marker = marker;
    }
}

Array.prototype.itemIndex = function(key, item) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if(this[i][key] == item) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
};

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5,  4.5),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
    overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function() {};
    overlay.setMap(map);

    //generateMarkers(pokemonData);
    generatePageMarkers(pokemonData);
}
    /**
    *  returns how many pixels the marker is from the map
    *  @see https://gist.github.com/keannan5390/3996774  (adapted by me)
    */
    function getPixelPosition (marker) {
      var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
      var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(
        map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
        map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
      );
      var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
      var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
      var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point(
        Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale),
        Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale)
      );
      return {
        x: pixelOffset.x,
        y: pixelOffset.y,
        right:  document.getElementById("map").clientWidth - pixelOffset.x,
        bottom: document.getElementById("map").clientHeight - pixelOffset.y
      };
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```